# TestNG XML creation by read the test suite excel file

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

***Can someone please help to create a selenium TestNgXML file dynamically through Java Program for below format.***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="InetBankingV1">
  
  <listeners>
  <listener class-name="com.appName.Demo.TestListener"/>
  </listeners>
  
  <test thread-count="5" name="Banking Test">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.appName.testCases.TC001_Test1"/>
      <class name="com.appName.testCases.TC002_Test2"/> 
     <class name="com.appName.testCases.TC003_Test3"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Class names will be read from the excel file(which is a test suite, controlling the execution) only for those testcases marked as yes in the Excel.
FYI, Excel file which controls execution(test suite engine)contains columns TCName, Run(yes/No) and class name for each test.

Answer (score 0):

this program helps you to know creating testng suite programmatically

```
 https://gist.github.com/sayems/7087c47c5009dedac339
```

Here for classes, u need collect required classes from excel and need to pass here..